# Sum and compare columns from different tables and databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables I'd like to compare.  They are in separate databases and servers as well.  I've added a linked server and can query this from within Server 1.

Table1 on Server1 provides breakdowns of submitted data.  For example **ref#123** may appear 3 times with values of 100, 150, and 200 (total **450**). I want to compare Table2 on Server2 that also has **ref#123** and the totals, and return the correct record if the total is different to **450**.

Hope this makes sense! Thanks

Comment: What does "return the correct record" mean?

Comment: probably phrasedf wrongly - more like the 'incorrect' record.  i.e. return record from table2 where the total is not equal to that from table1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from
(select col1, SUM(col2)
from table1
group by col1) t1 INNER JOIN
(select col1, col2
from table2) t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 where t1.col2 <> t2.col2
```

> table 1 is table where ref#123 can appear multiple times.
>   col2 contains values 100,150,200 e.t.c

Comment: I'm getting incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where':
`select *
from
( select submission_id, sum([mileage covered])
 from tbl_weekly_expenses
 group by submission_id
) t1 inner join
(
 select subid, sum(miles)
 from server.database.dbo.tblExpensesMileage
 group by subid
) t2 where t1.submission_id > t2.subid`

Comment: @Zohaib -1, check the results - there will be nearly cross join and there will not be results missed in one of tables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
      ref,
      SUM(values) values
    FROM Server1.YourDb1.YourSchema.TableBreakdowns
) t1
FULL JOIN Server2.YourDb1.YourSchema.TableTotals t2
  ON t1.ref = t2.ref
WHERE t1.values <> t2.values OR t1.ref is null OR t2.ref is null
```